# How do I get html5 color picker working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, color-picker

I tried using

```
<input type="color" style="border:none">
```

to get the render color picker onto the web page. However, this is not working in IE11. How do I get it working? I cannot to open source color pickers available online to get my task done. Please help me with an appropriate solution. If using third party pickers the only viable option, please let me know of it.

Answer (score 1):

IE and Safari do not have the functionality implemented as of now
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color

You might want to try a polyfill

https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum

https://github.com/dciccale/nativeColorPicker

https://github.com/jonstipe/color-polyfill